# Adjust Cucumber with Playwright Config Ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumber, playwright

I'm using both Cucumber and Playwright, which means that my playwright.config.ts file is redundant. However i would like to use some of the features that playwright offers (for examples, SlowMo or timeout set in the playwright config ts. file) How can i do so? I have already tried to specify config file explicitly with --config flag, also added node --no-warnings=ExperimentalWarning --loader ts-node/esm {file} but this still doesnt work. I keep getting following errors :

```
This Node.js version (v20.9.0) has not been tested with this version of Cucumber; it should work normally, but please raise an issue if you see anything unexpected.
Error: Cucumber expected a CommonJS module at '{file}' but found an ES module.
      Either change the file to CommonJS syntax or use the --import directive instead of --require.

      Original error message: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests-1\src\tests\specs\allocation-page\grid-tests.spec.ts
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of {file}from C:\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests-1\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\try_require.js is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from package.json.
```

--config file is set to the playwright.config.ts file. I also added "type":module to the package.json and expected type as "ESNext" if i switch it to the commmonJS i receive different problem (something with the exports)

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible code example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example